# flask db migrate not working sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file (Background on this error at:

Tags: python, microservices, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to run flask db migrate and it gives me this error

I have tried multiple solutions from the internet but none of them seem to be working and I am unable to find the problem here myself

The program has been successfully run on the server. What I need to do is modify something on it. Since the production server is not allowed for testing, I tested it in the development server locally via flask. However, I could not run even the original program. Below is from python.

```
PS C:\Users\Alam\Desktop\docker_demo\user> flask db migrate
 * Ignoring a call to 'app.run()' that would block the current 'flask' CLI command.
   Only call 'app.run()' in an 'if __name__ == "__main__"' guard.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\engine\base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
           ^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\pool\base.py", line 325, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\pool\base.py", line 888, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\pool\base.py", line 491, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\pool\impl.py", line 256, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\pool\base.py", line 271, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\pool\base.py", line 386, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\pool\base.py", line 684, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\util\compat.py", line 210, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\pool\base.py", line 680, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\engine\create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\engine\default.py", line 598, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__
.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\cl
i.py", line 1047, in main
    cli.main()
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\co
re.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\co
re.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\co
re.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\co
re.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\co
re.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\de
corators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\cl
i.py", line 357, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\co
re.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_mi
grate\cli.py", line 104, in migrate
    _migrate(directory, message, sql, head, splice, branch_label, version_path,
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_mi
grate\__init__.py", line 111, in wrapped
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_mi
grate\__init__.py", line 170, in migrate
    command.revision(config, message, autogenerate=True, sql=sql,
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\alembic\
command.py", line 229, in revision
    script_directory.run_env()
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\alembic\
script\base.py", line 569, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\alembic\
util\pyfiles.py", line 94, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\alembic\
util\pyfiles.py", line 110, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Alam\Desktop\docker_demo\user\migrations\env.py", line 97, in <module> 
    run_migrations_online()
  File "C:\Users\Alam\Desktop\docker_demo\user\migrations\env.py", line 82, in run_migra
tions_online
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\engine\base.py", line 3315, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\engine\base.py", line 96, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\engine\base.py", line 3394, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\engine\base.py", line 3364, in _wrap_pool_connect
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\engine\base.py", line 2198, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\util\compat.py", line 210, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\engine\base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
           ^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\pool\base.py", line 325, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\pool\base.py", line 888, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\pool\base.py", line 491, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\pool\impl.py", line 256, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\pool\base.py", line 271, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\pool\base.py", line 386, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\pool\base.py", line 684, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\util\compat.py", line 210, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\pool\base.py", line 680, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\engine\create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\engine\default.py", line 598, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Here is my code
#app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from routes import user_blueprint
from flask_migrate import Migrate
import models

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'jknfjajm'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///./database/user.db'
models.init_app(app)
app.register_blueprint(user_blueprint)

migrate = Migrate(app, models.db)
app.run()
```

#routes.py

```
from flask import Blueprint,jsonify
from models import db, User

user_blueprint = Blueprint('user_api_routes',
                           __name__, url_prefix='/api/user')

@user_blueprint.route('/all', methods = ["GET"])
def get_all_users():
    all_user = User.query.all()
    result = [user.serialize() for user in all_user]
    response = {
        'message': 'Returning all users',
        'result': result
    }
    return jsonify(response)
```

## models.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin

db = SQLAlchemy()


def init_app(app):
    db.app = app
    db.init_app(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    api_key = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=True)
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    authenticated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<user {self.id}, {self.username}>'

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'username': self.username,
            'is_admin': self.is_admin,
            'api_key': self.api_key,
            'is_active': self.is_active
        }
```

---

---

Comment: for anyone having same problem. My issue was resolved by changing app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///./database/user.db' to app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///C:\\filepath\\database\\user.db'

Answer (score 0):

for anyone having same problem.

My issue was resolved by changing this is the solution for windows. if you are using linux or Mac your path string might differ, but as of python there shouldnt be much of difference other than "/" or ""

Change `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///./database/user.db'` to `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///C:\\filepath\\database\\user.db'`